# Notation for sorting a word

Tags: notation, article-writing, combinatorics-on-words

Is there an established notation for sorting finite sequences/words? At the moment, I have written the following definition:

> For a word $\textbf{a} = a_1, \dots, a_t$, let $\operatorname{Sort}(\textbf{a}) :=
>  a_{\sigma(1)}, \dots, a_{\sigma(t)}$ where $\sigma$ is a permutation
> such that $a_{\sigma(1)}\le a_{\sigma(2)} \le  \dotsb\le a_{\sigma(t)}$.

This is for combinatorics paper I intend to submit to the Arxiv. I am also a little self-conscious that the inclusion of permutations is unnecessary and may cause confusion, so any feedback about that is also welcome.

Note: $a_i$ are all integers so this is all well-defined, just a little verbose

Comment: What if there there are two different permutations that sort your word?

Comment: Also, is that the standard notation for words?

Comment: This is why I'm worried about confusion, there can be multiple permutations which sort a word, but they will all produce the same result. If $\textbf{a} = 1,1$, then both $\sigma = e$ and $\sigma = (1\,2)$ sort the word, however we get $\operatorname{Sort}(\textbf{a}) = 1,1$ either way. As we never do anything which depends on the original indices of letters, there is no effect to the end result.

Comment: Just say "...is a (not necessarily unique) permutation..."

Answer (score 2):

Using words (with a non standard notation) is not a good idea in this case. What you are really doing is the following: you start with a finite sequence $S$ of integers and you produce the sequence $\text{Sort}(S)$ of elements of $S$ in increasing order. For instance, if $S = (2, -1, 0, -1, 3, 2)$, then $\text{Sort}(S)$ is the sequence $(-1, -1,0,2,2,3)$. As you can see, permutations are not needed.

Your notation $\text{Sort}(S)$ makes sense and I would keep it.